# Como puedo usar un subString con input en python?

Tags: python

muy buenas estuve creando un código de prueba para un ejercicio, pero no pude lograrlo. La idea es que tome el primer número como inicio de un subString y el segundo la longitud del mismo. Algo así por ejemplo: frase: 'Desarrollando' num1: 4 num2: 8 salida: rrolland

```
print("Escoga dos numeros y una frase")
posicion = input("Introduzca el primero numero: ")
longitud = input("Introduzca el segundo numero: ")
frase = input("Introduzca una frase: ")



sub_frase = frase[int(posicion):longitud]
print(sub_frase)
```

Comment: Qué resultado devuelve el código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que el valor que tomas de la entrada por teclado de usuario `input()` por defecto es un string. Si intentas acceder a un rango de la cadena `frase` con esos strings va a dar el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Se me ocurren tres maneras de arreglarlo:

**1. Valorando los `input()` con `int`:**

```
posicion = int(input("Introduzca el primero numero: "))
longitud = int(input("Introduzca el segundo numero: "))
```

De esta manera se aplica la función `int()` sobre el input, esta función `int()` devuelve el literal tipo entero de un string (si es válido). Entonces cuando se invoque el rango se hará con números enteros.

**2.Invocando el rango con los literales enteros:**

La misma función `int()` se puede aplicar cuando se vaya a invocar el rango de la cadena en cuestión, tomando los `input()` como string.

```
sub_frase = frase[int(posicion):int(longitud)]
```

**Evaluando con `ast.literal_eval()` (más literales):**

Se puede evaluar el rango de la cadena en cuestión con variables string, por medio de la función `literal_eval()` del modulo `ast`:

```
import ast

posicion = ast.literal_eval(f"{posicion}")
longitud = ast.literal_eval(f"{longitud}")
```

**Solución a tu problema:**

De las tres manera que ejemplifique con la primera ya debería de funcionar bien: (ni sé para que puse las demás xDDDDD):

```
print("Escoga dos numeros y una frase")
posicion = int(input("Introduzca el primero numero: "))
longitud = int(input("Introduzca el segundo numero: "))
frase = input("Introduzca una frase: ")

sub_frase = frase[posicion:longitud]
print(sub_frase)
```

Ejecución:

```
Escoga dos numeros y una frase
Introduzca el primero numero: 1
Introduzca el segundo numero: 4
Introduzca una frase: holaa
ola
```

Espero que te haya servido, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

La función `input` retorna siempre un objeto clase `str`. Si lo que requieres son valores `int` para ser utilizados en otra operación (como es este caso) hay que hacer un *casting* (es decir, convertirlo a otro tipo de datos):

```
num1 = int(input("Ingrese la posicion inicial: "))
num2 = int(input("Ingrese la posicion final: "))
sub_str = cadena[num1:num2+1]
```

El `num2+1` es porque el *index-slicing* reduce en una posición el alcance del rango.